# SQL isn't new data after the existing ones, misorder

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm inserting data into my sql database through php using this code

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(cid, instrument, otime, volume, oprice, type, ctime, cprice, commission, swap, profitloss)VALUES('$pcid', '$pinstrument', '$potime', '$pvolume', '$poprice', '$ptype', '$pctime', '$pcprice', '$pcommission', '$pswap', '$pprofitloss')";
```

All data inserted came after each other, meaning first record inserted is at the top of table then second bellow it and etc. the problem came when I deleted a row, also through php using the code below, afterwards new records are inserted in the place of the old records, not at the bottom of the table.

```
$sql="DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
```

Anybody knows why? attached more info about my database[picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSVql.png)  [pciture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVzp0.png)

Comment: The order of rows isn't defined in relational databases. If you need to process data in a specific order, you have to use the `ORDER BY` clause to relate it to specific columns.

Comment: if you just check the id of the new row it will be higher than the last one previously inserted. Mysql doesn't have such an "order" concept. The order is on how you sort the table. You are not sorting it by id so you see the data in a different order than what you expect.

Comment: Now I’m sorting by id but when I request the data through php it doesn’t come out in order, old isn’t first.

Comment: This code looks like it will be crazy-vulnerable to sql injection issues.

Comment: @Sultan There is no SQL database that will re-use ID values (identity, sequence, autoincrement, etc) on it's own. As long as you `ORDER BY` ID, you will see the correct order, because the ID values for records inserted later will always be larger. It will not back-fill previous ID values after deletion, unless you specifically write extra code to make that happen (and you should NOT do this). If you don't use an `ORDER BY`, that specifically implies that you **don't care** about the order, and you **must** put up with whatever order the databases, even if it's not what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order by clause is the trick

I was using

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
```

But when I added ORDER BY to become this

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY id";
```

It worked as desired.

Credit to Barmar for the hint